# Creating a simple timesheet in HTML/Java

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to make a simple timesheet and I got stuck. I'm trying to ONLY show the months between 2 days (`finalDayEnd` and `initialDayEnd`).

**I already got the dates via my session variable.**

[image]

**Example:** Let's say `initialDayEnd` is 04/10/2017 and `finalDayEnd` is 01/01/2018

**My Month Tag Should display October,November,December for 2017 and January for 2018.**
In this case I would need to start table days in 4 instead of 1 for month October and end in 01 for January 2018.

How can I get the Months and years between 2 dates and how to start on the initialDay and end of finalDay.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Individual" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <%
                        String initialDayEnd = session.getAttribute("initialDayEnd").toString();
                        String finalDayEnd = session.getAttribute("finalDayEnd").toString();
                    %>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <label>Month:</label>
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">January
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">January</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">February</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">March</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <label>Year:</label>
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">2017
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">2017</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2018</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2019</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <%
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    SimpleDateFormat ft  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(2017,1,19);
                    int days = localDate.lengthOfMonth();
                    Date date;
                %>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">#</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Day</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Number of Clients</th>
                        <th class="text-center"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <%
                        for(int day = 1;day<=days;day++) {
                            date = sdf.parse(day+"/10/2017");
                    %>
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td><%=day%></td>
                        <td><%=ft.format(date)%></td>
                        <td><input name="amountOfClients[]" type="number"></td>
                        <td>
                            <%
                                if(day == 1) {
                            %>
                            <input type="checkbox" <%--<%= environment.isPaused() ? "checked='checked'" : ""%>--%> data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" value="Repeat">
                            <label> Repeat for All?</label>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `"How can I get the Months and years between 2 dates"` - I'd start by converting those string date values to something like a `LocalDate` or a `YearMonth`.  Once it's a proper date value instead of just a string then you can easily perform calculations on it.  For example, you could write a loop to start at the first date end after passing the second date, adding a month each iteration and recording the name of that month in an array.  At the end of the loop the array should contain the list of month names.

Comment: @David that wasn't very helpfull.

Comment: Well, what have you tried and what isn't working?  If the approach I suggested doesn't work in some way, how does it fail?  How does your own approach fail?

Comment: I tried this : https://i.gyazo.com/885ebb568e93cfa7456e1c56e299b492.png and outputs: Sat Feb 04 00:00:00 GMT 2017
Sat Mar 04 00:00:00 GMT 2017
Tue Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Thu May 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Sun Jun 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Tue Jul 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Fri Aug 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Mon Sep 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Wed Oct 04 00:00:00 BST 2017
Sat Nov 04 00:00:00 GMT 2017

Comment: It should output just October because my initial and final date were 2017-10-04 and 2017-10-06

Comment: It looks like the loop itself is working, but the start and end dates don't match what's in the question.  What are the runtime values being used?  Perhaps the strings aren't being parsed to the correct date values due to a culture difference?

Comment: It's exactly this: 2017-10-04 and 2017-10-06

Comment: wth xD i debugged. https://i.gyazo.com/b42bb8745ae52a1af3d7ab1d1b33f515.png

Comment: he converts 10 to january

Comment: Looks like the format string is wrong.  `"DD"` is for the day of the *year*, not the day of the *month*.  `04` and `06` are indeed the 4th and 6th of January.  Use `"dd"`.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening @David

Comment: @David now it shows only February. It should be october

Comment: You're explicitly setting the month to `i`, so you're starting from the beginning of the year every time.  Get rid of `i` entirely and set the month with something like: `date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is convert those string values to actual date values, it'll make any math *a lot* easier.  Something like this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date startDate = format.parse(initialDayEnd);
Date endDate = format.parse(finalDayEnd);
```

From there you could use a loop from one date to the next, incrementing by month, and adding the name of the month to an `ArrayList`.  As a quick example, something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();
while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
    months.add(new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[startDate.getMonth()]);
    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
}
```

Afterward, the `months` list would have the names of all the months between the start date and the end date.

(Note: I'm getting deprecation warnings on `getMonth()` and `setMonth()`.  There appear to be updated versions using a `Calendar` object, with which I am unfamiliar.  My Java-specific knowledge is a bit dated, but the concept is still the same regardless of the objects used.)

Comment: almost perfect but if the start and end date are in the same month I dont get any output

Comment: @xaa: You don't?  I do.  Is your end date somehow before your start date in that test?

Comment: i tested with 2017-10-04 initial and 2017-10-06 final

Comment: @xaa: Same here.  The loop executes once and the list has the single value `"October"` afterward.  When you debug, does the loop execute at all?  What are the runtime values each step of the way?

Comment: it works now. But it's in Portuguese ( my language) i want english